# I am unable to see output on pycharm console , code is without error

Tags: python, html, url, pycharm, urllib

I want to print all urls which have on particular webpage. Below code is without error but unable to see the desired result on pycharm console. Any help will be appreciated . On console only 'hello' appeared. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
from sgmllib import SGMLParser
import urllib


class URLLister(SGMLParser):
    def reset(self):
        SGMLParser.reset(self)
        self.urls = []

    def start_a(self, attrs):
        href = [v for k, v in attrs if k == 'href']
        print href
        if href:
        self.urls.extend(href)


usock = urllib.urlopen("http://diveintopython.org/")
parser = URLLister()
parser.feed(usock.read())
print "hello"
usock.close()
parser.close()
for url in parser.urls:
   print url
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint after the 'parser.close()' and look into the parser.urls closely. Seems like it is empty.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> usock = urllib.urlopen("http://diveintopython.org/")
> ```

I suspect you mean...

```
usock = urllib.urlopen("http://diveintopython.NET/")
```

...which does work with your code.